# Why does CLI QEMU use the full terminal width at boot time, but not when using nano or gdb?

Tags: linux, qemu

I currently am launching a RISC-V qemu session as follows:

```
/usr/bin/qemu-system-riscv64 -machine virt -m 4G -smp cpus=2 -nographic \
    -bios /usr/lib/riscv64-linux-gnu/opensbi/generic/fw_jump.bin \
    -kernel /usr/lib/u-boot/qemu-riscv64_smode/u-boot.bin \
    -netdev user,id=net0 \
    -device virtio-net-device,netdev=net0 \
    -drive file=qemu_disk.bin,format=raw,if=virtio \
    -device virtio-rng-pci \
    -vga virtio \
    -no-reboot
```

The `-vga virtio` in particular was necessary to get it to use the full terminal width at boot time, as shown below:
[image]

However, if I open an application like nano or gdb from within the qemu VM, it stops using the full width of the enclosing terminal window, as shown below:
[image]

How can I tell QEMU to behave as if it has more space, so that applications like nano and gdb recognize this when launched?

(Note: I subsequently found I can install the "resize" tool, and manually run it, but I'm wondering if there's a way to just have qemu handle this automatically.)

Comment: In the terminal window what does `stty -a | grep -oP 'columns \K\d+'` return? What about `echo $COLUMNS`?

Comment: The first screenshot shows only output from programs that don't attempt to use the terminal's characteristics, while the second shows an attempt -- and lack of underlying configuration information -- so you get the default 24x80.

Comment: @roaima both commands show "80".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering "why":

**`nano`** and **`gdb`** use the same information that **`stty`** shows, since that usually is good enough.

The first screenshot shows only output from programs that don't attempt to use the terminal's characteristics, while the second shows an attempt -- and lack of underlying configuration information -- so you get the default (looks like 25x80).

If you look closer, **`qemu`** doesn't *own* the console, and can't get good information.  For instance, it might actually be connected via a pseudo terminal.  That's easy to see in other programs.  Here's an example where I'm using *screen*.  The *stty* program gives the right size, but lets me pretend that it's a different size.  That (in reverse) is what *resize* does: calculate the correct size using the terminal's escape sequences and update the settings used by *stty*.

[image: example of stty ignored]

If qemu doesn't have a workaround built-in, using *resize* (or something like it) is the solution.